# Assign multiple variables at once in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a vector params1 and I want to assign the values in them to multiple variables like below. Any suggestions?

```
params1 = [1 2 3 4]
[a,b,c,d] = someFun(params1)
```

Comment: `deal` is the function you are looking for, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, but deal copies all numbers to all variables. Not 1-to-1.